# Information about a file or directory

Tags: linux, windows

1. In Linux, the information about a
   file or directory is stored in its
   inode. I was wondering what is the
   data structure for information about
   a file or directory in Windows 7?
2. How to get the information about a
   file or directory in Linux and in
   Windows 7, in terminal and command
   line window?
3. Is the owner of a file or directory
   always its creator? Will it be able
   to change?
4. Is there a creation timestamp for a
   file in Linux and in Windows 7? How to
   get it?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Linux, the information about a file or directory is stored in its inode. I was wondering what is the data structure for information about a file or directory in Windows 7?

In both operating systems, this depends on which file system is being used.

Windows uses [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) by default, which has ["attribute lists"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Internals) in its Master File Table. There is some documentation in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Internals), at [NTFS.com](http://www.ntfs.com/) and [Linux NTFS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linux-ntfs/files/NTFS%20Documentation/).

The older [FAT32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32) filesystem (still used often in removable drives) is much simpler, and keeps everything in a single [file allocation table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table).

> How to get the information about a file or directory in Linux and in Windows 7, in terminal and command line window?

In Linux, use the `stat` command.

In Windows PowerShell, use [`System.Io.FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx).

In Windows `cmd.exe`, you have to use either external tools or mess with `dir`.

> Is the owner of a file or directory always its creator? Will it be able to change?

- On Windows NT *(including XP, 2003, Vista, 7, and future versions)*, newly created objects<sup>1</sup> are owned by their creator, unless someone else takes ownership. (Administrators can do this by using `SeTakeOwnership` privilege; non-Administrators can take ownership if the object's ACL allows it.)

  - On server editions of Windows NT, Administrators can *assign* object ownership to another user. Consumer editions (such as Windows XP or 7) only allow *taking* ownership to yourself.
  - In Windows 2000 and earlier versions, if the creator is member of the Administrators group, the objects he creates will be owned by Administrators, not the user. [This changed in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318825), where the user will always own objects he creates.
  - The FAT filesystems *do not support* file ownership.
- All<sup>[citation needed]</sup> Unix systems use the file's creator as its owner.

  - `root` can use `chown` to change the owner.

> Is there a creation timestamp for a file in Linux and in Windows 7? How to get it?

- In Windows, both FAT32 and NTFS store a creation timestamp. In `cmd.exe`, **`dir /tc`** will show it.
- FreeBSD's UFS2 stores the creation time as [`st_birthtime`](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2006-June/124813.html).
- On Linux, creation times are supported by some filesystems (ntfs, possibly ext4), but [not yet by the OS itself](https://www.redhat.com/archives/ext3-users/2006-October/msg00015.html). (The `stat` command already shows birth times, if supported by the syscall of same name.)

*Note:* On Windows and FreeBSD, the creation time is easy to change.

---

<sup>1</sup> This applies to many other types of Windows NT objects, not limited to files. Examples: named pipes, Registry keys, processes, services, desktops, devices, mutexes...

Comment: Correction: in Unix systems owner can change ownership with `chown` too.

Comment: @ulidtko: Incorrect. See [Linux](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/chown.2.html) ("Only a privileged process (Linux: one with the CAP_CHOWN capability) may change the owner of a file."), [BSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chown&sektion=2&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE) ("...the change _owner_ capability is restricted to the super-user")...

Comment: @ulidtko: ...and [Unix 7th Edition](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chown&sektion=2&manpath=Unix+Seventh+Edition&format=html) ("Only the super-user may execute this call, because if users were able to give files away, they could defeat the (nonexistent) file-space accounting procedures." – Windows follows the same reasoning). // The _group_, however, _can_ be changed – if the user is a member of the target group.

Comment: True, I was wrong.

Comment: @ulidtko: And this SU question: http://superuser.com/questions/164526/why-unprivileged-user-cant-change-file-ownership

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about Windows 7, but will try to answer Linux parts.

1. True, except for file name.
2. The [`stat(1)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/stat/) utility can get all the information about an inode. Accompanying syscall, [`stat(2)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/stat/) can be used in your programs.
3. No, the owner of a file or directory can be changed in any moment, see [`chown(8)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/chown/). See also [sticky bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit).
4. No, in Linux the creation timestamp is not stored. See the [`stat(2)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/stat/) syscall, specifically the `struct stat` definition. Last access time (`st_atimespec`), modification time (`st_mtimespec`) and inode data modification time (`st_ctimespec`) are available.

Comment: Re #4 - it _can_ be stored, it's just not accessible through `stat(2)` (yet).

Comment: Does "(2)" in "stat(2)" mean the category in manpage of "stat(2)"?

Comment: @grawity Though this is non-standard (non-POSIX) feature and very unlikely will be available on other systems. Use at you own courage.

Comment: @Tim yes.      [placeholder]

Comment: @ulidtko: [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stat&sektion=2&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-stable), [OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/stat.2.html) and NetBSD already have (varying) implementations of `st_birthtime`. I heard Solaris does too.

Comment: @grawity and Linux have not. Standard-less mess.